# SharedPreferences return null when retrieving values

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save some values with `SharedPreferences` as key-value pairs when the app closes or is destroyed and retrieve them when the app is opened again.
The issue is that when I call to retrieve the values, it returns `null`.

I have tried passing the context or getting the application context and making the values `static`, but it does not seem to work.

```
class SavedValues {

private static final String keyP1fName = String.valueOf(R.string.player_1_name_key);
private static final String keyP1Game = String.valueOf(R.string.player_1_game_key);
private static final String keyP2fName = String.valueOf(R.string.player_2_sname_key);
//Have other strings here

private MainGame mainGame;

SavedValues(MainGame mainGame) {
    this.mainGame = mainGame;
}

//private SharedPreferences mPrefs = mainGame.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
private SharedPreferences mPrefs = mainGame.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());


void saveMainGameValues() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
     editor.putString(keyP1fName, mainGame.fullNameP1.getText().toString());
     editor.putString(keyP1Game, mainGame.gameScoreP1.getText().toString());

     editor.putString(keyP2fName, mainGame.fullNameP2.getText().toString());
     editor.putString(keyP2Game, maingGame.gameScoreP2.getText().toString());
     editor.apply();
}

void getMainGameValues() {
    mPrefs = mainGame.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (mPrefs.contains(keyP1fName)) {
    mainGame.fullNameP1.setText(mPrefs.getString(keyP1fName, "Player 1"));
    mainGame.gameScoreP1.setText(mPrefs.getString(keyP1Game, "0"));

    mainGame.fullNameP2.setText(mPrefs.getString(keyP2fName, "Player 2"));
    mainGame.gameScoreP2.setText(mPrefs.getString(keyP2Game, "0"));
}}
}
```

And I am trying to call these in my main activity's **onStart/onStop** and so on methods

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    //savedVals.getMainGameValues();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    savedVals.getMainGameValues();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    savedVals.saveMainGameValues();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    savedVals.saveMainGameValues();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    savedVals.saveMainGameValues();
}
```

I should be getting the last retrieved values or at least the default ones, but instead the app crashes and get the following error for the callback in onStart or onResume:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.andygix.a40love.SavedValues.getMainGameValues()' on a null object reference
    at com.andygix.a40love.MainGame.onResume(MainGame.java:379)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1364)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7490)
```

Comment: Check for null value for savedVals variable if(savedVals!=null){savedVals.getMainGameValues();} in your onResume

Comment: Is it not the SavedValues the null one here? Have you properly instantiated your savedVals

Comment: Where are you initializing `savedVals`? Exception says that `savedVals` is null, not your strings in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: first you have to check a null in shared preference value used to check with debug point on this I think issue in save value.

Comment: @Khojiakbar savedVals is initialized in the main activity in the onCreate method:
savedVals = new SavedValues(this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `SavedValues` class having logical error.

When your class will be initialized, the constructor will be called and `mainGame` get some value but **before that you are create `mPref` variable so it has no value.** You have to initialize `mPref` in constructor.

Here I have updated class.. Try to replace and check.

```
class SavedValues {

    private static final String keyP1fName = String.valueOf(R.string.player_1_name_key);
    private static final String keyP1Game = String.valueOf(R.string.player_1_game_key);
    private static final String keyP2fName = String.valueOf(R.string.player_2_sname_key);

    private MainGame mainGame;


    /**************************** THIS PART I CHANGED *******************/


    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    SavedValues(MainGame mainGame) {
        this.mainGame = mainGame;
        mPref = mainGame.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**********************************************/

    //private SharedPreferences mPrefs = mainGame.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    void saveMainGameValues() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(keyP1fName, mainGame.fullNameP1.getText().toString());
        editor.putString(keyP1Game, mainGame.gameScoreP1.getText().toString());

        editor.putString(keyP2fName, mainGame.fullNameP2.getText().toString());
        editor.putString(keyP2Game, maingGame.gameScoreP2.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
    }

    void getMainGameValues() {
        mPrefs = mainGame.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (mPrefs.contains(keyP1fName)) {
            mainGame.fullNameP1.setText(mPrefs.getString(keyP1fName, "Player 1"));
            mainGame.gameScoreP1.setText(mPrefs.getString(keyP1Game, "0"));

            mainGame.fullNameP2.setText(mPrefs.getString(keyP2fName, "Player 2"));
            mainGame.gameScoreP2.setText(mPrefs.getString(keyP2Game, "0"));
        }}
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Worked. It skipped my mind that I should have it in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, You can accept answer and do upvote if it helps you.